# How to report TODOs and other tags with CruiseControl?

Tags: java, ant, cruisecontrol

In one project the use of `//TODO`, `//XXX` and `//FIXME` tags is very common.

The problem is that nobody has an overview of all TODO lines - only Eclipse shows all the tasks in one view.

I would like to display all TODOs with filenames in our daily build report created by CruiseControl.

How can this be achieved easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html).  But I'd look into [this Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/) - maybe you can generate tag reports without migrating your build wholesale from Ant.

Comment: Perfekt. I will try the checkstyle and the maven plugin. Both seem very nice.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a small script that "grep" for all //TODO tags in your soruce code files and prints a report. This script can then be called from ant so that the build output contains this report.

Comment: -1: grep isn't able to distinguish the different locations of TODO tags like eclipse can do it. If you have a string containing your TODO tag somewhere in your code, grep would find it, creating a warning in your report.

Comment: I used the word "grep" in a generic way. You could always write your search string such that it ignores such possibilities. For ex. search for only uppercase TODO that start with // etc.

Comment: @tangens: is it really often when you have `//TODO` in your Strings literals?